# Project really has no decent constraints yet, why is it giving me this constraint warning every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Every time I run my project, I get this warning in the console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x8cc6830 UITableView:0xb3f5c00.contentHeight{id: 112} == -7.000000>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   <_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x8cc6830
>   UITableView:0xb3f5c00.contentHeight{id: 112} == -7.000000>
>
> Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
>   methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful.

It's from a UITableView, and I'm definitely not touching the UIScrollView directly. It only has a label in each cell with these constraints:

[image]

I Googled and Googled but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know why it's complaining about UIScrollView?

Comment: Do you use -()estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath ? I have the same type of conflict (but very very rare), and it seems to be about NSfetchedresulcontroller calling for a change in the tableview vs tableview controller trying to evaluate the height (with heightForRow) vs ??? And in my case, removing the -()estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method seems to diminished the risk of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove the warnings, the quickest way to do it is in the storyboard.
[image: add / remove constraints]

select the view controller that causes the warnings to be displayed and select: clear all constrains in yourViewControllersName.

another option will be to select: reset to suggested constrains in yourViewControllersName.

these action will either clear all constraints, or add what ever Xcode thinks are the most suitable constraints to the view controller.

resting to suggested constraints will sometimes (or is it always?) add constraints that will not fit your needs..